# How can I force a Hebrew font to match the fixed width of Latin text characters in a mono font

Tags: fonts, unicode

I have setup my Emacs to use Noto Sans Mono everywhere. I did this on the naïve assumption that it was in fact a mono-spaced font, with full coverage of Hebrew and Greek Extended characters. Unfortunately, while it does have that codepoint coverage, the character widths are very different and it is only monospaced for some unicode ranges.

Is there a way to force Emacs to use fixed character widths with a font, despite the font having variable widths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Emacs did that, the characters would overlap. You’ll want to choose a different font, or to modify the default fontset so that it uses a different font for Hebrew characters. See the function `set-fontset-font`, documented in chapter [22.15 Modifying Fontsets](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Modifying-Fontsets.html) in the Emacs manual (which you can also open inside Emacs with `C-h i`).